# Offline UIWebView viewing old images

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, caching, uiwebview

I have created a `UIWebView` that runs offline in an iOS app.  I'm utilizing a certain javascript library to display virtual tours and that is why I need to use `UIWebView`.

I'm now having an issue upon running the application: Much of the time it is displaying old images even though they are not in the resources or have been updated. I've tried many things to remedy this including setting the cache policy:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"splash2" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

On the very top of my `viewDidLoad` I've tried setting the cache capacity:

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

And this on my application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

Currently I have in my `viewDidLoad`

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];


    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"splash2" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];

    webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;

    webView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

    for (id subview in webView.subviews)
        if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
            ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;


    [super viewDidLoad];
```

I've also tried in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"splash2" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]];

    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];


    NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];


    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];


    webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;

    webView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

    for (id subview in webView.subviews)
        if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
            ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;


    [super viewDidLoad];
```

Also I'm not sure if it has to do with html5 manifest.  All and all, I just want need it to turn caching off and always read what exists currently in my resources.

Comment: It's quite a vague explanation...